# Where to find the URL I need to put in Sharepoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I know for a fact that there's somewhere a page in Sharepoint that shows the URL you're supposed to enter in Sharepoint Designer to open the site.

I just can't find any link to get to it. Does anyone know where I'm supposed to look ?

Comment: You can add normal site url.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't work in every cases.
I ended up finding what it was though: `_admin/SharePointDesignerAdmin.aspx` !

Comment: can you give an example of case in which the normal site url wont work please?

Comment: I have literally no idea why or how this happens. I've just been given access to a Sharepoint Server on which it is the case.

Comment: I've never dealt with a site I couldn't connect to by using the standard url, is the _admin/ aspx page a way of allowing designer access for users with central admin access on sites where designer may be otherwise disabled? I've never seen such a page either :)